# Readonly is not working in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Inside my `HTML` file:

```
<rating ng-show = "onerate =='null'" readonly="isReadOnly" ng-model="newRate.rating" max="max" class="assertive" ng-click="addRating('{{singleRecipe[0].recipe_id}}')" >
</rating>
```

I want that whenever I click once it will never be clickable.

Inside my `controller` in my `Javascript` file:

```
$scope.rate = 1;
$scope.max = 5;
$scope.isReadonly = false;
$scope.newRate = {};
$scope.newRate.userID = $scope.userdata.user_id;
$scope.addRating = function(recipe_id){
   $scope.newRate.recipeID = recipe_id;
   RatingList.add($scope.newRate);
   console.log($scope.newRate);
   $scope.isReadonly = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ng-readonly` docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly)

Keep in mind that readonly attribute only works for input objects, if you are creating some element that responds to click, you will have to handle this differently.

What you really want is to change your click method:

```
$scope.addRating = function(recipe_id){
  if (!$scope.isReadonly)
  {
    $scope.newRate.recipeID = recipe_id;
    RatingList.add($scope.newRate);
    console.log($scope.newRate);
    $scope.isReadonly = true;
  }
}
```

You use `ng-class` with `$scope.isReadonly` to dynamically add classes to visually show that the element is no longer clickable if you wanted to. More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: im my database its right... but i can still click rating

Comment: This depends on what the <rating> element is exactly, it seems there is more in the UI than you have shown in your code example. I would suggest creating a new question with all the information needed to get a good answer to your next problem

Comment: Can you please add what should be written in my view

Comment: <rating> is a plugin, its a star rating.

Comment: sorry i am not familiar with this plugin, however I am sure there is a way to disable the control, just use $scope.isReadonly as the boolean to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ng-readonly**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly

You now have only **readonly**